# Problems returning result of CDbCriteria based query

Tags: yii

I have a query as follows

```
$criteria1 = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria1->condition = 'id = 1';
$modelA=Table1::model()->find($criteria1);
```

I can pass it to a view and return the title and entry

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbBox', array(
title' => $modelA['title'],
'content' => $modelA['entry'] ));
```

Now I'd like to return a range of entries

```
$criteria2 = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria2->condition = 'id > 7';
$modelB=Table1::model()->findAll($criteria2);
```

(btw : I'm following a form as laid out [here](http://sonsonz.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/yii-examples-of-using-cdbcriteria/)). I was expecting to be able to read the resulting array of values out as below, but ['title'] is now being seen as a undefined index (obviously I'm expecting to read this out in a loop but you get the point)

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbBox', array(
'title' => $modelB['title'][0],
'content' => $modelB['entry'][0]));
```

Where am I going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the indexes should be specified in the different order: the number of a specific element first, then the name of the property. Additionally, it's better (=cleaner) to name the result of `findAll` so it'll show you (and any other reader) that it's a collection, not a single model:

```
$models = Table1::model()->findAll($criteria2);
// ...
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbBox', array(
  'title' => $models[0]['title']
  //...
));
```

But even that's not necessary if you use `foreach` (and you probably will):

```
foreach ($models as $model):
// ...
  $this->widget('some.name', array(
    'title' => $model['title']
  );
endforeach;
```